# Difference between git reset --hard HEAD~1 and git reset HEAD~1 --hard?

Tags: git

To the best of my understanding `git reset --hard HEAD~1` and `git reset HEAD~1 --hard` do the same thing, employing different forms of `git reset`:

`git reset [<tree-ish>] [--]`  (first form in the [git reset help file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset))

`git reset [--] [<commit>]` (third form)

Is this correct? Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: What are "these git commands"? You mention no concrete commands. If you mean the ones in the subject, please be specific.

Comment: I replaced "these git commands" with the specific commands mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the full synopsis:

```
git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>…​
git reset (--patch | -p) [<tree-ish>] [--] [<paths>…​]
git reset [--soft | --mixed [-N] | --hard | --merge | --keep] [-q] [<commit>]
```

In the first two forms, you are *not* allowed to use the `--hard` flag. Both of your commands will thus refer to the last form. The Git CLI allows you to re-order flags for convenience — as long as there's no ambiguity.